# Aggregating a dataframe dynamically with column names in strings from another dataframe

Tags: r

Ok, so I have a configuration dataframe that will specify, how I want to aggregate a few columns in another dataframe.

config frame:

```
conf <- rbind(                                                                                                                                                                  
    c("a", "cnt"),                                                                                                                                                    
    c("b", "cnt")                                                                                                                          
    )
```

And a dataframe of data

```
dd <- data.frame(cbind(c("a1", "a1", "a1"), c("b1", "b1", "b2"), c(1, 2, 3)))
names(dd) <- c("a", "b", "cnt")
```

And I want to run basically this command:

```
aggregate(cnt ~ paste(conf[, 1], collapse=" + "), data=dd, sum)
```

Which would ideally return

```
output
a1  b1 3
a1  b2 3
```

Make sense?  I feel like i'm missing something with do.call or eval on getting the dynamic column names.  Or maybe intersecting the names(dd) list with conf[, 1]

Comment: I guess you mean `colnames(dd)` ..not `names(dd)`

Comment: You should be able to use `?as.formula`

Comment: as.formula was totally what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks easier to me (after correcting your sinful ways):

```
dd <- data.frame( c("a1", "a1", "a1"), c("b1", "b1", "b2"), c(1, 2, 3))
names(dd) <- c("a", "b", "cnt")

aggregate(dd$cnt , dd[ as.character(conf[, 1]) ], sum)
#--------
   a  b x
1 a1 b1 3
2 a1 b2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Stealing @Justin's suggestion here's what I ended up doing.

```
aggregate(as.formula(paste("cnt", 
                           paste(conf[,1], collapse=" + "), 
                           sep=" ~ ")), data=dd, sum)
```

Comment: Which would fail for the data you offered because you sinned against R and used `data.frame(cbind(...))`